# Property only set after change of focus at binded input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my xaml I have a textbox which is binded to a property in my viewmodel:

XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding City}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
```

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public string City
    {
        get { return _model.Address.City; }
        set
        {
            if (_model.Address.City != value)
            {
                _model.Address.City = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Two-way-data-binding works well but it seems that a properties value is only set when the focus is changed from the city input to another object.

I would like to save my context when a hotkey (ENTER) is pressed. When I now enter a city and press ENTER afterwards, the property doesn't contain the new value. When I enter a city, change the focus to another object and press ENTER, the property contains the right value.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming your example code is just a typo ... you are showing a binding to a `Country` property, but your VM shows a `City` property.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `UpdateTrigger` and set it to `PropertyChanged`.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Country, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. I enter a city, press ENTER and then the value of the property is still NULL.

Comment: @mosquito87 do you have any binding errors in the output?

Comment: @mosquito87 does your Address class implement `iNotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: The set method of the property is not called. Doesn't have to do anything with binding. It's only called once the focus is changed.

Comment: Sure it does. Data binding is working fine. The only problem I have is that the setter of the property is only called once the focus was changed.

Comment: have you tried to set the `Mode` for the binding to `TwoWay` in the xaml?